# Why does LastIndexOf give error: "Length cannot be less than zero"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my code which should display some data from the mode. At the moment I have no data:

```
<div class="desc-plus-products align-centre ">
    @{
        var TheString = "";

        if (item.Name.Length == 0)
        {
            TheString = "Empty Name String";
        }
        else
        {
            TheString = item.Name;
        }


        var maxLength = 20;

        var trimmedString = TheString.Substring(0, Math.Min(TheString.Length, maxLength));
        trimmedString = trimmedString.Substring(0, Math.Min(trimmedString.Length, trimmedString.LastIndexOf(" ")));
    }
    <p>@trimmedString</p>
    <p>£@item.Price</p>
</div>
```

The error is the following:

```
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Source Error: 


Line 112:
Line 113:                                var trimmedString = TheString.Substring(0, Math.Min(TheString.Length, maxLength));
Line 114:                                trimmedString = trimmedString.Substring(0, Math.Min(trimmedString.Length, trimmedString.LastIndexOf(" ")));
Line 115:                            }
Line 116:                            <p>@trimmedString</p>

Source File: D:\Websites\websitename\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 114
```

I would have thought that the `if statement` would make the error go away since I check if the string is empty, if it is, I set the string to a temporary one to be used with the `length` method.

Comment: Use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of checking the string length.

Comment: [String.LastIndexOf(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy(v=vs.110).aspx) returns -1 if the substring is not found.

Comment: wouldn't `trimmedString.LastIndexOf(" ")` return a -1 if there are no occurrences of a space?  given the choice of 0 and -1, -1 is the min, can't ask for index -1

Comment: @Kritner You're correct except that it's length, not index of -1 that it's asking for.

Comment: This would have been fairly easy to spot if you had actually debugged the code, did you try doing that?

Comment: @apk I was just about to put that as the answer until I refreshed the comments here. Why don't you go ahead and answer the question and expand upon the reason it is failing.

Comment: @gmiley Because this is a poor question that needs to be deleted, not answered?

Comment: It can still be answered, if it gets deleted then nothing lost. If it doesn't then at least there is an answer associated with it. I don't see the point in purposely not answering a question, even if it is of poor quality. It isn't going to change the fact that the question was asked in the first place.

Comment: @gmiley I would suggest spending time answering valuable questions, instead of potentially wasting time adding an answer to a question that may get deleted. OP has their answer in the comments, this question can now go away and everyone is happy.

Comment: No offense intended, but you you're preaching about wasting time answering a poor question after having edited that question to improve it, and continue posting comments on it. I guess it just comes down to what each person considers a waste of time, and to me answering a question, even a poor one, if it helps someone isn't a waste of time - at least to me.

Comment: @gmiley None taken, but it took me 3 clicks to make that edit, and I did it before I knew the answer. Answering takes a lot longer to do (properly at least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @apk - the issue you are having is on line 114, as indicated in your question, and related to the call to `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`.

```
trimmedString = trimmedString.Substring(0, Math.Min(trimmedString.Length, trimmedString.LastIndexOf(" ")));
```

The call to `LastIndexOf()` has the potential to return `-1`, which is what is generating your error:

> Length cannot be less than zero.
>
> Parameter name: length

In fact, right there in your posted question it says the specific line number where this error is occurring. Also, to reiterate what was mentioned in the comments, stepping through this in the debugger would have immediately led you to where the problem was. In the future, putting even just a little bit of effort into the debugging process will save you a lot more time than immediately posting your error here and waiting for a response (that may never come).